# How to convert RTCVideoFrame/RTCI420Buffer to RTCCVPixelBuffer?

Tags: ios, webrtc

when I add a renderer to my **remote** video track, then the `onrenderFrame` event is fired with an `RTCVideoFrame` that contain an `RTCI420Buffer` buffer. When i do the same on a **local** video track, then no problem it's fire with an `RTCCVPixelBuffer`.

- How I can convert the `RTCI420Buffer` to an `RTCCVPixelBuffer`?
- Is their any way to force the `onrenderFrame` of remote video track to fire with an `RTCCVPixelBuffer` ?

This is how I add the renderer to the remote video track :

```
    aTransceiver := nil;
    for I := 0 to fpeerConnection.transceivers.count - 1 do begin
      aTransceiver := tRTCRtpTransceiver.Wrap(fpeerConnection.transceivers.objectAtIndex(i));
      if aTransceiver.mediaType <> RTCRtpMediaTypeVideo then aTransceiver := nil
      else break;
    end;
    if aTransceiver = nil then raise Exception.Create('No remote video track founded');
    fRemoteVideoTrack := TRTCVideoTrack.Wrap((aTransceiver.receiver.track as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);
    fRemoteVideoTrack.retain;
    fRemoteVideoTrackRenderer := TRemoteVideoTrackRenderer.create(self);
    fRemoteVideoTrack.addRenderer(fRemoteVideoTrackRenderer.GetObjectID);
```

Comment: I found in the latest version of googleWebrtc framework you can get RTCCvPixelbuffer without converting the frame.

can you specify what is your target so that I can help you more in this?

Comment: @sumitmeena: Yes i get RTCCvPixelbuffer but only from local video track. when i do with remote video track I have only RTCI420Buffer. I just updated the question to show you the code of how I create the renderer.

Comment: You got any solutions to this?